# Bowser disable cross domain cookies in Firefox for opening Visualforce page in an automated browser

Tags: automation, webdriver, salesforce

I am trying to open a Visualforce page in Firefox using an automation tool (Web driver). While trying this, every time automated browser open the VF page it shows:

> We can't display this page because your browser blocks cross-domain
> cookies. Try again with a different supported browser.

How to run automation test script for the VisualForce Pages?